# In MAAS, how can I use my own ubuntu image for fast installer

Tags: maas

I am using Maas to organize my cluster and save time.

There is a option in Maas node: fast install, which can use a image to install system directly.

I was wondering if I can make that image of my own. so that I do not need to install software,too!